# Unable to login https://dashboard.honeygain.com using cookies

Tags: authentication, cookies

I want to login https://dashboard.honeygain.com/ using the cookies I get from [J2TEAM Cookies](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/j2team-cookies/okpidcojinmlaakglciglbpcpajaibco/reviews) Chrome plugin.

There are my steps:

1. Go to https://dashboard.honeygain.com/login and click "Accept All".
2. Login with my email and password so that I can get my honeygain cookies.
   [image]
3. Use the export button of J2TEAM Cookies to export my cookies as a json file.

[image]
4. Delete the cookies of honeygain in my Chrome browser.

[image]

5. Go to https://dashboard.honeygain.com/login and import the cookies I exported in step 3 using J2TEAM Cookies, then refresh the page.
   [image]
6. I expect that I can see my honeygain profile at this moment. But what I actually see is the login page of honeygain.

Why can't I login honeygain using the cookies I just exported?

Does honeygain use some techiques to prevent users from doing this kind of activtiy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dashboard.honeygain.com uses both cookies and localstorage in my browser to identify me.

[image]

So in order to login Honeygain without using my email and password, I also have to export and restore localstorage in step 3 and 5 respectively.

I use [LocalStorage Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/localstorage-manager/fkhoimdhngkiicbjobkinobjkoefhkap) plugin to export and restore my localstorages.